Truncation error of adjacent central divided differences
Given a smooth real-valued function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$. For the non-equidistant grid points $x_{i-1}<x_{i}<x_{i+1}$, $\Delta x_{i}:=x_{i}-x_{i-1}$ and $\Delta x_{i+1}:=x_{i+1}-x_{i}$, consider the derivatives $f^{'}(x_{i-0.5})$ and $f^{'}(x_{i+0.5})$ at the midpoints $x_{i-0.5}=x_{i}-\frac{\Delta x_{i}}{2}$ and $x_{i+0.5}=x_{i}+\frac{\Delta x_{i+1}}{2}$ respectively. Then the following central difference representations are used in a FVM:
$$
f^{'}(x_{i-0.5})=\frac{f(x_{i})-f(x_{i-1})}{\Delta x_i}+\frac{(f^{'''}(\xi_{l,i-0.5})+f^{'''}(\xi_{r,i-0.5}))}{48}\Delta x_i^2\\
f^{'}(x_{i+0.5})=\frac{f(x_{i+1})-f(x_{i})}{\Delta x_{i+1}}+\frac{(f^{'''}(\xi_{l,i+0.5})+f^{'''}(\xi_{r,i+0.5}))}{48}\Delta x_{i+1}^2
$$
for some $\xi_{l,i-0.5}\in (x_{i-1},x_{i-0.5})$, $\xi_{r,i-0.5}\in (x_{i-0.5},x_{i})$, $\xi_{l,i+0.5}\in (x_{i},x_{i+0.5})$ and $\xi_{r,i+0.5}\in (x_{i+0.5},x_{i+1})$.
Subsequently, I want to prove that the local truncation error of the difference satisfies
$$
f^{'}(x_{i+0.5})-f^{'}(x_{i-0.5})=\frac{f(x_{i+1})-f(x_{i})}{\Delta x_{i+1}}-\frac{f(x_{i})-f(x_{i-1})}{\Delta x_i}+\mathcal{O}(\Delta x_{i+1}^2-\Delta x_{i}^2),
$$
which presumably can be established through a suitable factor $M$ such that
$$
\frac{(f^{'''}(\xi_{l,i+0.5})+f^{'''}(\xi_{r,i+0.5}))}{48}\Delta x_{i+1}^2-\frac{(f^{'''}(\xi_{l,i-0.5})+f^{'''}(\xi_{r,i-0.5}))}{48}\Delta x_i^2
$$
is bounded by $M|\Delta x_{i+1}^2 - \Delta x_{i}^2|$. Any hints or advises how to proceed with the last claim are appreciated.
